# DBMS_XQUERYINT package has compilation errors

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to insert an xml file into oracle table. I got the error  as
**ORA-19114: error during parsing the XQuery expression:

ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SYS.DBMS_XQUERYINT' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:**
I figured out that I need to have DBMS_XQUERYINT object in my db. I ran the package available ...product\10.2.0\server\RDBMS\ADMIN. But package is not getting compiled successfully. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Find the errors in the package: `select * from dba_errors where name = 'DBMS_XQUERYINT';`

Comment: Did you install Java? It's required.

Comment: @dcieslak, i dont have initjvm.sql in the .../admin folder. where can i get that.

Comment: @JonHeller,  the errors are 1. PLS-00311: the declaration of "oracle.xquery.OXQServer.bindXML(int, java.lang.String, oracle.xdb.XMLType)
     return int" is incomplete or malformed. 2. PLS-00905: object SYSTEM.DBMS_XQUERYINT is invalid. i think initjvm.sql is required.

Comment: i@dcieslak, i have jave 1.6

Comment: Check [http://abcdba.com/abcdbaserverinstallguideshowtoinstalloraclejvm](http://abcdba.com/abcdbaserverinstallguideshowtoinstalloraclejvm)

Comment: I didn't find the initjvm.sql. Should i download that component seperately?

Comment: What edition are you using?  Express Edition does not include Java.

Comment: correct, mine is 10g express edition. i didnt find any downloads, available